# GCC dependencies generation full path

Tags: gcc, makefile

In a makefile I am trying to build the list of dependencies for a cpp file. This is the structure of the makefile:

```
DEPS=dep_file
build:
     $(MAKE) dep_file;
     .....
dep_file:
     @$(GXX) -MM $(file_path) | $(SED) 's/\.o:/.cpp.html:/' >$(DEPS)
```

I am getting this error when caling the build target for the file CC_Interface.cpp:

```
/prj/comp/cc/base/src/CC_Interface.h:42:17: CMF.h: No such file or directory
/prj/comp/cc/base/src/CC_Interface.h:43:25: Data.h: No such file or directory
/prj/comp/cc/base/src/CC_Interface.h:44:26: UTMsg.h: No such file or directory
/prj/comp/cc/base/src/CC_Interface.cpp:53:26: bb/Elem.hpp: No such file or directory
/prj/comp/cc/base/src/CC_Interface.cpp:56:18: BB.hpp: No such file or directory
...............
```

In /prj/comp/cc/base/src I have CC_Interface.h/cpp.
In /prj/comp/bb/ I have Elem.hpp

I want to obtain the full path when building the file with dependencies in the dep_file target from makefile. I was triyng -M, -MM, -MM -MT but it doesn't work.

Comment: This makefile has serious problems. How long is it? Could you post the whole thing? And are you trying to build `dep_file` so that this makefile can use it?

Answer (score -1):

There is a section in the manual on generating prerequisites automatically.  You may not need to follow the whole thing, but at least follow the general setting up of targets, prereqs, and recipe.